# Combining `With`, `If` and SetDelayed

Tags: evaluation, conditional, assignment

I just noticed that

```
With[{x = 1}, If[x == 0, 0, 1]]
```

returns `1` (as I expected) but

```
y := If[x == 0, 0, 1];
With[{x = 1}, y]
```

returns an unevaluated form:

```
If[x == 0, 0, 1]
```

Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: `With` makes a "literal" replacement of the instances of `x` that appear in the code that follows the list. When the code is `y`, there is "literally" no `x` present.  So no substitution is made, and ***then*** `y` is evaluated, the `x` appears, but the replacement time is over.

Comment: @kglr I might suggest `Block[{x = 1}, y]`.  @A.G., see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs

Comment: For these short examples, `Trace` can be a good tool to use and be familiar with.  Try `With[{x = 1}, y] // Trace`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mathematica* is an expression rewriting language. `With[{x = 1}, y]` rewrites `y` with every `x` replaced by `1`. `With` has the `HoldAll` attribute, so `y` is left unevaluated before the rewrite takes place.

But `y` contains no `x`, so the the result is simply `y`. Then, since `y` has an ownvalue, it gets rewritten as `If[x == 0, 0, 1]`.